# image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, mysql, blob

```
<?php
//include database connection
include("include/db.php");

//select the image
$query = "SELECT image FROM fresult WHERE result_id = 1";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('SQL error');


while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    header("Content-type: image/jpg");


    //display the image data
    print $row1['image'];
    //exit;
}

?>
```

What is wrong with this code? I don't understand.

I try to do simple code to retrieve the image. I use xampp, SQL blob.

Comment: So is that a SQL error or PHP error?

Comment: What's the format of the image column? is it a path to where the image is located?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, it looks like all you have to do is switch your header to read:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

`image/jpg` isn't a content-type header.

If you post the image data in a comment, I might be able to be of more assistance.

Hope this helps.

[php](/questions/tagged/php) [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) [jpeg](/questions/tagged/jpeg) [db](/questions/tagged/db)